# laravel log system with logstash

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I have a laravel application that I want to store my logs into my logstash  and see them in kibana i searched a lot over the net to find a solution for it but I didnt find any good source for it, is there any package to use laravel logs into logstash ???
by the way  I have my logstash and kibana running without any problem I just need a source of data now .
and here is my elstic search running :

```
    {
name: "5351ced3b7a4",
cluster_name: "elasticsearch",
cluster_uuid: "Ej5TRN8CQyGvemZlT3gAFA",
version: {
number: "7.1.1",
build_flavor: "oss",
build_type: "tar",
build_hash: "7a013de",
build_date: "2019-05-23T14:04:00.380842Z",
build_snapshot: false,
lucene_version: "8.0.0",
minimum_wire_compatibility_version: "6.8.0",
minimum_index_compatibility_version: "6.0.0-beta1"
},
tagline: "You Know, for Search"
}
```

EDIT
as the answer explains the way I did and now I get this error in my logs in laravel  :

```
[2019-08-05 14:16:17] laravel.INFO: Hello logstash!
```

EDIT :
The Logging Config file :

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Log Channel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option defines the default log channel that gets used when writing
| messages to the logs. The name specified in this option should match
| one of the channels defined in the "channels" configuration array.
|
*/

'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log channels for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Drivers: "single", "daily", "slack", "syslog",
|                    "errorlog", "monolog",
|                    "custom", "stack"
|
*/

'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Laravel Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'critical',
    ],

    'papertrail' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'level' => 'debug',
        'handler' => SyslogUdpHandler::class,
        'handler_with' => [
            'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
            'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
        ],
    ],

    'stderr' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stderr',
        ],
    ],

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'errorlog' => [
        'driver' => 'errorlog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
    'logstash' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via'    => \App\LogstashLogger::class,
        'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT', 9200),
    ],
],

];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [this post](https://medium.com/@bauernfeind.dominik/using-logstash-with-laravel-509c65065d52) it's quite easy to do.

1. Configure a logging channel in `config/logging.php` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#configuration))

```
    'channels' => [
        // ... other channels like stack or single
        'logstash' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via'    => \App\LogstashLogger::class,
            'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT', 4718),
        ],
    ],
```

2. Create a custom Logger factory ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#creating-channels-via-factories))

```
namespace App;

use Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\SocketHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class LogstashLogger {
    /**
     * @param array $config
     * @return LoggerInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): LoggerInterface
    {
        $handler = new SocketHandler("udp://{$config['host']}:{$config['port']}");
        $handler->setFormatter(new LogstashFormatter(config('app.name')));
        return new Logger('logstash.main', [$handler]);
    }
}
```

This will write logs via udp to the specified host and port using the [monolog logstash formatter](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LogstashFormatter.php)

3. To now write log entries to logstash specify the logging channel you just created ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#writing-to-specific-channels))

```
Log::channel('logstash')->info('Hello logstash!');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it gives the error in log like this : [2019-08-05 14:16:17] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class App\\LogstashLogger does not exist at /home/farshad/my-projects/tika_acco/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790)

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `logging.php` and `LogstashLogger`?

Comment: Done it was my tinker cache and after i reseted that no error and no log happened so i assume that its working . is there any way to if its working or no because i could not find it in kibana ??

Comment: My guess would be that it should show up in kibana if logstash is configured correctly. However my expierence with logstash is minimal, so I can't really help you beyond that.

Comment: ok i accepted your answer as the right one but i dont know if i am sending data to logstash or not yet :)

Comment: You could try opening another SO question for that specific issue, it might get you the answers you need

Comment: This is not sending data to elastic search as i queried in and nothing was there

Comment: Then you could try another way by writing this log channel to a file and loading that file up in logstash. Otherwise you might need to debug your setup a bit more

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't working for me because of the UCP socket connection, rather than debugging it I just changed it to TCP and it worked.

I first tested it on the command line:

```
echo "hello world!" | nc 127.0.0.1 5000
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to update your elastic configuration, otherwise s/udp/tcp.

```
$handler = new SocketHandler("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
$formatter = new LogstashFormatter('EXAMPLE');

$handler->setFormatter($formatter);

$logger =  new Logger('logstash.main', [$handler]);
```